Python Value exception
I am a Python learner and just on the Exception module. I wrote this code, need two int input and then calculate sum, otherwise ask the user to re-enter the number which is not valid.
Now, when num1 is not a number, the code can ask the user to re-enter, but when the second is not a number, it come to the top, asking to re-enter the first number, not the second.
flag = True
while flag:
    try:
        num1 = int(input("Please enter the first number:"))
        num2 = int(input("Please enter the second number:"))
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a number")
        continue
    else:
        sum = num1 + num2
        flag = False
    print(sum)

I expect the code to get the user to re-enter the number (num1 or num2) which the input is invalid.

Yes, if an exception occurs from either input, it'll enter the except block, and from there continue back to the top of the loop. You'll need to handle both possible exceptions separately.

Welcome to SO! This is a Q&A site, so what's your question exactly? Please [edit] to clarify. For tips, see [ask].

`def input_validated(string=None):
flag = True
while flag:
try:
num = int(input(string))
except ValueError:
print("Please enter a number")
continue
else:
flag = False
return num
num1 = input_validated("Please enter the first number:")
num2 = input_validated("Please enter the second number:")
sum = num1 + num2
print(sum)

@pippo1980 Don't put an answer in the question; that defeats the whole format of the site. If you believe this question is different enough from the linked one to deserve an answer, nominate it for reopening.

@wjandrea nope it is described in most voted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/23294659/9877065 in the Encapsulating it All in a Function paragraph
